# apirtc video call on cordova issue

Tags: webrtc

We are trying to integrate the apirtc video call feature in cordova. We have integrated it but somehow 90% of the time, the call does not go through.

Our app has 2 user types in the system who can video chat with each other. In database we have a unique user id generated for all registered users and the moment someone tries to call someone else we use the user id of the recipient to establish the call.

It works only 1 out of 10 times, the rest of the time it tries to connect and then automatically closes. Please can someone help us and let us know what is wrong.

I feel since we are using a constant number for calling that might be creating the issue, not sure. Should we generate random numbers each time call should be initiated?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix a constant number for each user like :

```
    apiRTC.init({
        apiCCId : USER_CONST, // one different number by user
        onReady: sessionReadyHandler,
        apiKey : "myDemoApiKey"
    });
```

If you don't fix a apiCCId, APIRTC will give a random number.

Did you try our sample app ? https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-mobile